# MySQL Insert NULL Inserts 0

Tags: mysql, select, update, null

I am using MySQL and PhpMyAdmin, I have a table named `items` - the structure is as follows;

```
+------+---------+------+---------+
| name | type    | Null | Default |
+------+---------+------+---------+
| id   | int(11) | No   | None    |
+------+---------+------+---------+
| year | int(4)  | Yes  | Null    |
+------+---------+------+---------+
```

Within PhpMyAdmin I run the following query;

```
UPDATE `item` SET `item_publication_year` = '' WHERE `item_id` = '5'
```

This executes successfully.

Then I run this query;

```
SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE `item_id` = '5'
```

This executes successfully and produces the following;

```
+-----+------+
| id  | year |
+-----+------+
| 5   | 0    |
+-----+------+
```

Why is the `year` field `0` - shouldn't it be `NULL`? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`''` is an empty string, it's **not** a `NULL` value.

Other DBMS would rightfully reject your update statement in the first place (because  it's invalid to assign a string to a number).

If you want to set something to `null` then use `null` not an empty string

```
UPDATE item 
  SET item_publication_year = null 
WHERE item_id = 5
```

---

You should also use the correct literal type for the data type. `'5'` is a string, it's not a number . `5` is a number. Not using the correctly typed literal might result in indexes not being used.

Comment: Given that `item_id` is `INT`, it will correctly convert `'5'` to `5`.  The other direction is a potential problem (number to `VARCHAR`).